# Redirect to home if url contains string with a dot using ,htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

My Wordpress site is under attack. A bot sends queries that crashes my **MySql**. All of them contains "**/?s=**" and "**.pl**" in the url, so, I whant to redirect to **home** if someone is trying to access them.
Example:

> If www.example.com/?s=xxxxx.pl redirect to www.example.com/
>
> If www.example.com/?s=123.pl redirect to www.example.com/

Can you help me? I couldn't find how to edit .htaccess to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a more robust system like [mod_qos](http://opensource.adnovum.ch/mod_qos/) to stop these types of attacks then it will automatically block them by IP and other ways.

However you can do something like this with rewrite rule and then it will get 403 forbidden.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} s=(.+)\.pl
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

if you still want to redirect to home page you can do this.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} s=(.+)\.pl
RewriteRule ^ /? [R=301,L]
```

Let me know how this works for you.

Comment: Hi, Panama Jack, thanks for your answer. The first option loads index page, but the url (and link rel="canonical") keeps the /?s=xxx.pl The second one, gives an error that says something like "site is redirecting too much times" (I don't know the message in english, my language is spanish) **ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS**

Comment: I made a slight change to the 2nd one. Clear your cache and try the second one again.

Comment: Thank you very much! Using 2nd one.